# How to deprecate a page in Trac?

Tags: deprecated, wiki, trac

Some Wiki have a feature to deprecate a page, for example by using templates. I searched on the Trac website and with a google search, without success.

How does one accomplish this in Trac?

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer on the Trac mailing list by Ryan J Ollos:

> There are currently no plugins that implement the feature as far as I know, but it would be fairly straightforward to implement. On trac-hacks.org we use a WikiExtras box macro and tag the page as deprecated. Example:
>   https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AdminEnumListPlugin

[image]

I report here the relevant source code of the page he linked:

```
{{{#!box warn
**Notice:** This plugin is deprecated in Trac 1.2 and later.
}}}
```

To be able to tag, one needs the [TagsPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TagsPlugin).